# Nested functional complexity issue fix in SonarQube version?

Tags: sonarqube

Just found a bug regarding "Do not include complexity of nested functions into nesting one complexity".

https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJS-729

It say's its fixed with version 2.15 in sonarsource. But i'm unable to find in what version of SonarQube, the same is fixed. Right now, we use SonarQube version of 4.5.6, but the issue still persist in that version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SonarJS 2.15 is not compatible with SonarQube 4.5.6: [since version 2.14](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJS-705), SonarJS requires SonarQube 5.6 or later.

You need to first upgrade to SonarQube 5.6 or later, and then upgrade SonarJS.